# Mamp localhost show's every folder except one

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I installed MAMP and have everything put in correctly, everything is running fine (for now). When I go to localhost/folderName/mainSiteFolder/subFolder/. I see every folder I need for my PHPMotion site (CSS, Images, Members_CSS, Member_Images, and Thirdparty. I am missing the folder Templates, which is there in my HTDOCS/siteName folder. All folders are read/write so why is it that this one folder that I need to work out of won't show when every other folder does.

Comment: Is it executable by the user/group? For directories, a user needs 'execute' in order to traverse into the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHPmotion, the /themes/YOUR_THEME/templates folder contains an .htaccess file which forbids access to it and its contents from a browser...none of the other folders (css, images, member_css, member_images, thirdparty) include this.  The template files are intended to be retrieved and processed through TBS, not viewed directly from a browser.